# change deployed app c# code without rebuild

Tags: c#, build

I need to find any solution to this problem:
each column in grid has it's own class used to calculate values.
sometimes it happens, that the calculation is wrong and I need to fix this on production immediately. But the hotfix runs only once a week.
I need to somehow be able to change the "calculate class" code without rebuild.
What I have think about is:
build the calculation class as external DLL and simply copy paste the wrong DLL, with a new one.
Will this work?

Comment: If you can recompile and replace a DLL, why can't you recompile and replace the EXE? What is the difference?

Comment: because I need to baypass the deployment approvement process, which involves filling up some documents and so on. I now it's weird, but for now it's the only way

Comment: Well of course you can do this then, as long as you take care to ensure that the new DLL has an interface that is 100% compatible with the old one. Indeed it is weird. It sounds like you really have an administrative problem that you are trying to solve with a technological solution.

Comment: yes, its an administrative problem together with problem, that I can not run  the build over night, because the app is used 24/5 worldwide, so build can only be run over weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replacing DLLs at runtime would require recycling in IIS.

Shadow copying is designed to take care of these kind of situations: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx